# getSubmittedValue() vs. getValue()

Tags: xpages

Is that correct:
When I query a value before validation (or if validation failed) I have to use `getSubmittedValue();`. Once the value is validated, even if I query it in another validation later in the page/control I have to use `.getValue();` since `getSubmittedValue();` returns *null* after successful validation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a slightly easier way: if you're just expecting a simple single-value String, just call:

```
var compare = firstField.getValueAsString();
```

Otherwise, call:

```
var compare = com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.convertValue(facesContext, firstField);
```

The former calls the latter anyway, but is obviously a terser syntax. This does what you're looking for and more:

1. If the value hasn't yet been validated, returns the submitted value
2. If validation has already passed, returns the value after it's already been processed by any converters and / or content filters, so particularly in cases where you're trying to compare two field values, this should ensure that both values have been properly trimmed, etc., and is therefore less likely to return a false positive than just comparing the raw submitted values.

Answer (score 3):

[This xsnippet](http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=getcomponentvalue) makes it easier to handle this. It allows you to just call `getComponentValue("inputText1")` to get either value or submittedValue.

Here's the function for reference:

```
function getComponentValue(id){
  var field = getComponent(id);
  var value = field.getSubmittedValue(); 
  if( null == value ){ 
         // else not yet submitted 
         value = field.getValue(); 
  }
 
  return value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260094/jsf-getvalue-v-s-getsubmittedvalue). So when you want to ensure that 2 text fields have the same value (use case: please repeat your email) and the first box already has a validation that might fail, you need to use submittedValue unless it is null, then you use the value. Code in the validation expression for the second field looks like this:

```
var firstField = getComponent("inputText1");
var compare = firstField.getSubmittedValue() || firstField.getValue();
compare == value;
```

You have to love it.