# JSF2.0 > multi-field validation - attributes are not set right

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, validation

I´m trying to implement a multi-field (e.g. two inputText-fields) validation under JSF2.0.
Unfortunally the attributes are not set right in the validator.

The behaviour is as follows:

When I submit the first entry of both input-fields the attributes in the validator are null. In the 2nd submit the values are filled correctly. In the 3rd submit I can see the values of the 2nd request, but not of the 3rd..
This is quite a strange behaviour.

In the following you can see my testcode.

**TestValidator.class**

```
@FacesValidator(value="testValidator")
public class TestValidator implements Validator {
    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value)   throws ValidatorException {

        UIInput c1 = (UIInput) context.getViewRoot().findComponent("input1");
        if (c1 != null) {
            Object s1 = (Object) c1.getSubmittedValue();
        }

        UIInput c2 = (UIInput) context.getViewRoot().findComponent("input2");
        if (c2 != null) {
            Object s2 = (Object) c2.getSubmittedValue();
        }

        String c5 = (String) component.getAttributes().get("input1");
        String c6 = (String) component.getAttributes().get("input2");
    }
}
```

I try to grab the attributes in two differnt ways. Unfortunally without success.
The parameter *value* is always set right.

**test.xhtml**

This is my first try with *f:attribute* attached to the 2nd inputText-field

```
<h:form id="test">

<h:inputText value="#{testModelBean.input1}" maxlength="10" size="4">
</h:inputText>

<h:inputText value="#{testModelBean.input2}" maxlength="10" size="4">

    <f:validator validatorId="testValidator" />

    <f:attribute name="input1" value="#{testModelBean.input1}" />
    <f:attribute name="input2" value="#{testModelBean.input2}" />

</h:inputText>

<h:commandButton action="#{testControllerBean.doAction}" /> 

</h:form>
```

This my 2nd with *h:inputHidden*:

```
<h:form id="test">

<h:inputHidden value="true">
       <f:validator validatorId="testValidator" />
       <f:attribute name="input1" value="#{testModelBean.input1}" />
       <f:attribute name="input2" value="#{testModelBean.input2}" />
    </h:inputHidden>

<h:inputText value="#{testModelBean.input1}" maxlength="10" size="4">
</h:inputText>

<h:inputText value="#{testModelBean.input2}" maxlength="10" size="4">
</h:inputText>

<h:commandButton action="#{testControllerBean.doAction}" /> 

</h:form>
```

In both cases the behaviour is the same as mentioned above.

My TestModelBean is quite simple

**TestModelBean.class**

```
@ManagedBean(name="testModelBean")
@SessionScoped
public class TestModelBean implements Serializable {

    private String input1;
    private String input2;

    public String getInput1() {
        return input1;
    }
    public void setInput1(String input1) {
        this.input1 = input1;
    }
    public String getInput2() {
        return input2;
    }
    public void setInput2(String input2) {
        this.input2 = input2;
    }

}
```

My TestControllerBean is simple too:

**TestControllerBean.class**

```
@ManagedBean(name="testControllerBean")
@SessionScoped
public class TestControllerBean 
implements Serializable {

    public String doAction() {
        return "success";
    }

}
```

Now my question is, if anyone has an idea, why the attributes are not filled right in every submit/request. Or is there a different way to access the attributes? Is there a certain order I should take care of (concerning DOM or JSF Lifecycle)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to misunderstand the lifecycle of JSF. Model values are updated at a later phase (Update model values phase) than JSF validation happens (Process validations phase). Therefore, when you expect to get a *new* model value *it's not been yet set*. As a consequence, you get the *old value* from your `@SessionScoped` bean.

See [Debug JSF lifecycle](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html) and [The JSF application lifecycle](http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/java/jsp-application-lifecycle-050504-1203/) for an overview of JSF lifecycle.

How can you overcome this situation? You can bind a full component as an attribute of the desired component and use [`UIInput`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html) methods [`UIInput#getValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIOutput.html#getValue%28%29) and [`UIInput#getSubmittedValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html#getSubmittedValue%28%29) respectively to get either the converted/validated value of component (for bound components that are located *before* the component in question in JSF component tree) or the raw submitted value (for bound components that are located *after* the component in question in JSF component tree).

All in all, you'd need to change your code to the following:

The view:

```
<h:inputText value="#{testModelBean.input1}" binding="#{input}" />
<h:inputText value="#{testModelBean.input2}">
    <f:validator validatorId="testValidator" />
    <f:attribute name="input1" value="#{input}" />
</h:inputText>
```

The validator method snippet:

```
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
    UIInput input = (UIInput)component.getAttributes().get("input");
    String inputString = (String)input.getValue();
    //etc.
}
```

See [JSF getValue() v.s. getSubmittedValue()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/260094/jsf-getvalue-v-s-getsubmittedvalue), [JSF doesn't support cross-field validation, is there a workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282466/jsf2-0-doesnt-support-cross-field-validation-is-there-a-workaround) and [JSF validate on submit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186086/jsf-validate-on-submit-form) for an overview.

Comment: Ok. Got that one. Thx. I changed the attributename of `UIInput input = (UIInput)component.getAttributes().get("input1");`. I now can access the value as needed.

Comment: You're welcome. As you're new to SO, please don't forget to mark the answer that most helped you in solving your problem as accepted.